# Why does my pg_query update method skips row?

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I'm just a beginner with php, even more so on PostgeSQL. I can say that my knowledge over php, json and sql is very limited.

I have created an update method to refresh my returned data whenever I create or delete a record from database. But sometimes, when I create a new record, the new record doesn't return from php until I use the refresh function twice. Sometimes, same happens too when I delete a record, I receive results one click late. This happens randomly, sometimes on first click, sometimes on 4th click.

Example: Let's say I have an existing record on table and added a new record. On by chance, it returned [["6","1","Jason Smith","&id","89"] when it should have returned [["6","1","Jason Smith","&id","89"][["6","1","King Sczhult","&id","90"], but when I check database or refresh the page by browser, the record is there.

```js
//The function that calls php
function refresh() {
   $(".scell").html(""); 
   $("#holidayCell").html("");
  
var updateTable = {
                        
  semSchedule: $("#semesterselect").val(),
  operation: "updateTable"
}

  $.post( "scheduleengine.php", updateTable).done(function( response ) {
  if (response.val != 0){
  //This is where I decode returned table array 
  }else {
  };
     
 

                
});
 };
```

```html
//This is the php switch-case.

switch($_POST["operation"]){
               
 case "updateTable":
             
  echo updateTableFunc(post("semSchedule"));
       
 break; 

//Update Function

function updateTableFunc($semID = null){
    
    
    
    $result = "";
   
    $scqrysql = "SELECT id, tutor, hour, day FROM schedule WHERE semester='$semID'";
    $scqry = pg_query($scqrysql) or die(pg_result_error());
        
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($scqry)) {
                
    $scTutorID = $row['tutor'];
    $tqry = pg_query("SELECT id, tname, tsurname FROM tutors WHERE id='$scTutorID'") or die(pg_result_error()); 
    while($tutorrow=pg_fetch_array($tqry)){
                
    $scTutor = $tutorrow['tname'] . " " .$tutorrow['tsurname'];
                
                                          };
            
     $scHourRow = $row['hour'];
     $scDay = $row['day'];
     $scID = $row['id'];
                
     $scHour = substr($scHourRow, 2, 1);
     $scDayNameArray = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday");
     $scDayNumberArray = array("2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
     $scDayNameReplace = str_replace($scDayNameArray, $scDayNumberArray, $scDay);
            
     $resultArrays = array($scDayNameReplace, $scHour, $scTutor, "&id", $scID);
     $result[] = $resultArrays;
                

                                        };
    
     if(is_null($result)){
     $result = "";
     echo json_encode($result);
     }else{
                
     $json = json_encode($result);
     echo $json;
         };
    
    
};
```

Comment: What is the code that calls this code? Is it perhaps doing a async query or using another DB connection somehow? You *MAY* want to run "commit" before running this code and see what happens.

Comment: I edited code snippet.

Comment: This is not the case either, I just tried "commit" both before update codes and after insert/delete queries.

Comment: If you wish to show your solution, do so in an answer post below. Please do not damage the original question, since that makes it harder (or impossible) for future readers to work out what you were originally asking. I have rolled back to an earlier version. (I sometimes repair these myself, but this one would have been too much work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem right there. Looks like you're using jquery to call both things, and you're doing it asynchronously-- meaning both kick off nearly instantly and either one could finish first (race condition). When "A" wins the race, you're golden.. when B wins the race you have to refresh again.
What you need is to call "A" (update query) then have it call "B" when it's finished.

Comment: It seems this is not the case, I completely omitted "var updateHolidays" from refresh function if this is what you meant. It became like this: script->php->updatefunc->echo json_encode($result)-> $(post(...  

I still encounter random skips.  I edited the code snippet accordingly.

Comment: I solved the problem with this approach. It was jquery. Thanks!